# my product variations come in arrays I need the function to regulate them

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let me give an example

these are coming to me.

```
Array
(
    [Renk] => Array
    (
        [0] => Altın Sarısı 
        [1] => Altın Sarısı 
        [2] => Altın Sarısı 
        [3] => Altın Sarısı 
        [4] =>  Gümüş 
        [5] =>  Gümüş 
        [6] =>  Gümüş 
        [7] =>  Gümüş 
        [8] =>  Siyah 
        [9] =>  Siyah 
        [10] =>  Siyah 
        [11] =>  Siyah 
        [12] =>  Beyaz
        [13] =>  Beyaz
        [14] =>  Beyaz
        [15] =>  Beyaz
    )
    [İnç] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15 
        [1] =>  16 
        [2] =>  17 
        [3] =>  18
        [4] => 15 
        [5] =>  16 
        [6] =>  17 
        [7] =>  18
        [8] => 15 
        [9] =>  16 
        [10] =>  17 
        [11] =>  18
        [12] => 15 
        [13] =>  16 
        [14] =>  17 
        [15] =>  18
    )

)
```

and I should do this.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Altın Sarısı 
        [İnç] => 15 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Altın Sarısı 
        [İnç] =>  16 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Altın Sarısı 
        [İnç] =>  17 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Altın Sarısı 
        [İnç] =>  18
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Gümüş 
        [İnç] => 15 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Gümüş 
        [İnç] =>  16 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Gümüş 
        [İnç] =>  17 
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Gümüş 
        [İnç] =>  18
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Siyah
        [İnç] => 15 
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Siyah
        [İnç] =>  16 
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Siyah
        [İnç] =>  17 
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Siyah
        [İnç] =>  18
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Beyaz
        [İnç] => 15 
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Beyaz
        [İnç] =>  16 
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Beyaz
        [İnç] =>  17 
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [Renk] => Beyaz
        [İnç] =>  18
    )
```

I use it but it turns too much.

```
function get_combinations($arrays) {
  $result = array(array());
  foreach ($arrays as $property => $property_values) {
    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($result as $result_item) {
      foreach ($property_values as $property_value) {
        $tmp[] = array_merge($result_item, array($property => $property_value));
      }
    }
    $result = $tmp;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please take the time to revise it, there is an `edit` link below it. It is unclear in the small code snippet you give at the end what the variables `$arrays` and `$result` actually contain. Without that no clear answer is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to long code to this purpose. Just iterate one key of array and create new array with target structure.

```
$newArr = [];
foreach ($arr['Renk'] as $key=>$item){
    $newArr[] = [
        "Renk" => $item,
        "İnç" => $arr['İnç'][$key]
    ];
}
```

Check result in [dmeo](https://3v4l.org/9EaP4)

---

Also if keys of array is dynamic, use code shown in bottom

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$newArr = [];
foreach ($arr[$keys[0]] as $key=>$item){
    $newArr[] = [
        $keys[0] => $item,
        $keys[1] => $arr[$keys[1]][$key]
    ];
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/OP4fe)

Comment: Renk and İnç in this case what should I do is not clear can multiply eg Renk, inç, Ram etc.